# how to show multiple comment_tree: ^0.3.0 in flutter , I want to show multiple comment in comment page Pleas help me

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test, flutter-renderflex-error

'here is comment widget i want to show this multiple comment widget in comment page and i also trying to lot of trying to put this comment widget in listview when i put this widget in listview my screeen is not rendered. but when i put this in gridview it is showing all comment properly plese help me'

```
import 'package:comment_tree/comment_tree.dart';
import 'package:comment_tree/widgets/comment_tree_widget.dart';
import 'package:ecllipsenew/data/repository/post_repo.dart';
import 'package:ecllipsenew/provider/PostProvider.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

import '../../../../util/app_constants.dart';

class Comments extends StatefulWidget {
  final List<Comment> commentList;

  Comments({this.commentList});

  @override
  State<Comments> createState() => _CommentsState();
}

class _CommentsState extends State<Comments> {
  bool reply = false;

  final List<Comment> commentLi = [
    Comment(
      avatar: 'nukkll',
      userName: 'njjull',
      content: 'I mkk interested',
    ),
    Comment(
      avatar: 'null',
      userName: 'null',
      content: 'I mjjj interested',
    ),
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Expanded(
          child: Container(
            child: CommentTreeWidget<Comment, Comment>(
              commentLi[0],
              [
                commentLi[0],
                commentLi[1],
              ],
              treeThemeData:
                  TreeThemeData(lineColor: Colors.blue, lineWidth: 3),
              avatarRoot: (context, data) => const PreferredSize(
                child: CircleAvatar(
                    radius: 18,
                    backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
                    backgroundImage: NetworkImage(AppConstants.User_Url)),
                preferredSize: Size.fromRadius(18),
              ),
              avatarChild: (context, data) => const PreferredSize(
                child: CircleAvatar(
                    radius: 12,
                    backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
                    backgroundImage: NetworkImage(AppConstants.User_Url)),
                preferredSize: Size.fromRadius(12),
              ),
              contentChild: (context, data) {
                return Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    Container(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8, horizontal: 8),
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Colors.grey[100],
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12)),
                      child: Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: [
                          Text(
                            '${data.userName}',
                            style: Theme.of(context)
                                .textTheme
                                .caption
                                ?.copyWith(
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                                    color: Colors.black),
                          ),
                          SizedBox(
                            height: 4,
                          ),
                          Text(
                            '${data.content}',
                            style: Theme.of(context)
                                .textTheme
                                .caption
                                ?.copyWith(
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
                                    color: Colors.black),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                    DefaultTextStyle(
                      style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.caption.copyWith(
                          color: Colors.grey[700], fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 4),
                        child: Row(
                          children: [
                            SizedBox(
                              width: 8,
                            ),
                            Text('5d'),
                            SizedBox(
                              width: 8,
                            ),
                            Text('Like'),
                            SizedBox(
                              width: 24,
                            ),
                            Text('Reply'),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                );
              },
              contentRoot: (context, data) {
                return Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    Container(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8, horizontal: 8),
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Colors.grey[100],
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12)),
                      child: Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: [
                          Text(
                            'Tina Chuhan',
                            style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.caption.copyWith(
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                                color: Colors.black),
                          ),
                          SizedBox(
                            height: 4,
                          ),
                          Text(
                            '${data.content}',
                            style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.caption.copyWith(
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
                                color: Colors.black),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                    DefaultTextStyle(
                      style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.caption.copyWith(
                          color: Colors.grey[700], fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 4),
                        child: Row(
                          children: const [
                            SizedBox(
                              width: 8,
                            ),
                            Text('5d'),
                            SizedBox(
                              width: 8,
                            ),
                            Text('Like'),
                            SizedBox(
                              width: 24,
                            ),
                            Text('Reply'),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                );
              },
            ),
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 12, horizontal: 16),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
    //       }

    //       );
    // });
  }
}
```

`and here is my comment show page`

```
import 'package:comment_tree/comment_tree.dart';
import 'package:ecllipsenew/screen/home/pages/comment/Comments.dart';
import 'package:ecllipsenew/screen/home/pages/comment/new_message.dart';
import 'package:ecllipsenew/util/app_constants.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class CommentPage extends StatefulWidget {
  static const routeName = '/Comment_Page';
  const CommentPage({Key key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  State<CommentPage> createState() => _CommentPageState();
}

class _CommentPageState extends State<CommentPage> {
  // final List<Comments> commentList = [
  //   Comments(
  //       commentId: "3",
  //       commentUserId: "11",
  //       commentUserName: "Himanshu",
  //       commentUserProfileImage: AppConstants.User_Url,
  //       commentType: "text",
  //       commentFile: "jjjj",
  //       commentDate: "12/12/12",
  //       commentTime: "12:30",
  //       commentReacts: "hhh",
  //       letestReplys: "jjjj")
  // ];

  final List<Comment> commentLi = [
    Comment(
      avatar: 'null',
      userName: 'null',
      content: 'I m interested',
    ),
    Comment(
      avatar: 'null',
      userName: 'null',
      content: 'I m interested',
    ),
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return
        //  Scaffold(
        //   appBar: AppBar(
        //     title: Text("Comment"),
        //   ),
        //   body:

        SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Container(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
//when I add this line my screen is not rendered
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) Comments(commentList: commentLi),
            Expanded(
              child: Comments(commentList: commentLi),
            ),
            NewMessage()
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
    // );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The main cause of render error is using Expanded widget inside Column, without having a fixed height for that Column.

If you want to use Expanded widget inside Column, you should wrap the column with a sizedbox and give it a fixed height as shown below:

```
SizedBox(
  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.8,
  child: Column(
    children: [
      Text('Header'),
      Expanded(
        child: Container(
          child: Center(
            child: Text('I take the remaining space'),
          ),
        ),
      )
    ],
  )
```

I could render the same code by removing the Expanded widgets wherever you have used them. They seem unnecessary too.

[Screenshot of commentPage by removing Expanded widget everywhere](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F6aEo.png)

Comment: plase post all code because i am begginner in flutter

Comment: Please find all code in another answer

Answer (score 0):

Please find full code as you have asked for in previous answer. Still, I recommend you to know the basic of flutter-layout to understand working with Expanded widget before using this code.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:test/view.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        title: 'Flutter Demo',
        theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        ),
        home: const CommentPage());
  }
}
```

Comments page code

import 'package:comment_tree/comment_tree.dart';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:test/test.dart';

```
class CommentPage extends StatefulWidget {
  static const routeName = '/Comment_Page';
  const CommentPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  State<CommentPage> createState() => _CommentPageState();
}

class _CommentPageState extends State<CommentPage> {
  // final List<Comments> commentList = [
  //   Comments(
  //       commentId: "3",
  //       commentUserId: "11",
  //       commentUserName: "Himanshu",
  //       commentUserProfileImage: AppConstants.User_Url,
  //       commentType: "text",
  //       commentFile: "jjjj",
  //       commentDate: "12/12/12",
  //       commentTime: "12:30",
  //       commentReacts: "hhh",
  //       letestReplys: "jjjj")
  // ];

  final List<Comment> commentLi = [
    Comment(
      avatar: 'null',
      userName: 'null',
      content: 'I m interested',
    ),
    Comment(
      avatar: 'null',
      userName: 'null',
      content: 'I m interested',
    ),
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text("Comment"),
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Container(
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) Comments(commentList: commentLi),
              // Comments(commentList: commentLi),
              // NewMessage()
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
    // );
  }
}
```

Comments tree page

```
import 'package:comment_tree/comment_tree.dart';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Comments extends StatefulWidget {
  final List<Comment> commentList;

  const Comments({Key? key, required this.commentList}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Comments> createState() => _CommentsState();
}

class _CommentsState extends State<Comments> {
  bool reply = false;

  final List<Comment> commentLi = [
    Comment(
      avatar: 'nukkll',
      userName: 'njjull',
      content: 'I mkk interested',
    ),
    Comment(
      avatar: 'null',
      userName: 'null',
      content: 'I mjjj interested',
    ),
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Container(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 12, horizontal: 16),
          child: CommentTreeWidget<Comment, Comment>(
            commentLi[0],
            [
              commentLi[0],
              commentLi[1],
            ],
            treeThemeData:
                const TreeThemeData(lineColor: Colors.blue, lineWidth: 3),
            avatarRoot: (context, data) => const PreferredSize(
              preferredSize: Size.fromRadius(18),
              child: CircleAvatar(
                  radius: 18,
                  backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
                  backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
                      "https://i.pinimg.com/736x/6f/de/85/6fde85b86c86526af5e99ce85f57432e.jpg")),
            ),
            avatarChild: (context, data) => const PreferredSize(
              preferredSize: Size.fromRadius(12),
              child: CircleAvatar(
                  radius: 12,
                  backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
                  backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
                      "https://i.pinimg.com/736x/6f/de/85/6fde85b86c86526af5e99ce85f57432e.jpg")),
            ),
            contentChild: (context, data) {
              return Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  Container(
                    padding:
                        const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8, horizontal: 8),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.grey[100],
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12)),
                    child: Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        Text(
                          '${data.userName}',
                          style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.caption?.copyWith(
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w600, color: Colors.black),
                        ),
                        const SizedBox(
                          height: 4,
                        ),
                        Text(
                          '${data.content}',
                          style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.caption?.copyWith(
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w300, color: Colors.black),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  DefaultTextStyle(
                    style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.caption!.copyWith(
                        color: Colors.grey[700], fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 4),
                      child: Row(
                        children: const [
                          SizedBox(
                            width: 8,
                          ),
                          Text('5d'),
                          SizedBox(
                            width: 8,
                          ),
                          Text('Like'),
                          SizedBox(
                            width: 24,
                          ),
                          Text('Reply'),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              );
            },
            contentRoot: (context, data) {
              return Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  Container(
                    padding:
                        const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8, horizontal: 8),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.grey[100],
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12)),
                    child: Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        Text(
                          'Tina Chuhan',
                          style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.caption!.copyWith(
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w600, color: Colors.black),
                        ),
                        const SizedBox(
                          height: 4,
                        ),
                        Text(
                          '${data.content}',
                          style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.caption!.copyWith(
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w300, color: Colors.black),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  DefaultTextStyle(
                    style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.caption!.copyWith(
                        color: Colors.grey[700], fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 4),
                      child: Row(
                        children: const [
                          SizedBox(
                            width: 8,
                          ),
                          Text('5d'),
                          SizedBox(
                            width: 8,
                          ),
                          Text('Like'),
                          SizedBox(
                            width: 24,
                          ),
                          Text('Reply'),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              );
            },
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```